# Solving System of Equations for $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Tags: linear-algebra

this is my first post, so please bear with me!

My linear algebra is a little rusty and I'm trying to solve this system of equations in a regression problem:

$$\alpha\left(x^Ty\right)+\beta\left(u^Tx\right)-\left(x^Ty\right)=0$$
$$a\left(u^Tx\right)+m\beta\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -\left(u^Ty\right)=0$$

I'm trying to solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and I have the solution, but my derivations aren't correct.

$$\alpha = \frac{x^Ty-\frac{1}{m}(u^Tx)(u^Ty)}{x^Tx-\frac{1}{m}(u^Tx)^2}$$
$$\beta = \frac{1}{m}u^T\left(y-\alpha x\right)$$

Can I get some help, please? Thank you!

Comment: Given the terms $\alpha(x^Ty)$ and $\beta(u^Tx)$, for the matrices to conform implies that $x$ is $n\times 1$, i.e. a vector, correct? In other words, this is simple linear regression and all the coefficients to your system are scalar?

Comment: Yes, $x$ is a column vector. Correct, this is simple linear regression and all the coefficients are scalar.

Comment: Does my answer help or are you still having trouble with the last step?

Answer (score 1):

You are close!

I am assuming **simple** linear regression (i.e. $x$ a vector) as otherwise it seems the matrices do not conform. This means all the coefficients are scalar, and you can use a number of methods for solving this system of two equations with two unknowns. For example, you might try to express $\beta$ using the second equation and substitute the expression obtained into the first equation.

I believe this is what you attempted as your expression for $\beta$ looks correct to me. Thus, using your $\beta$ and substituting into the first yields:
$$
\alpha(x^Ty)+\frac1mu^T(y-\alpha x)(u^Tx)-(x^Ty)=0
$$
Factoring out $\alpha$ yields the portion on the denominator (your numerator seems correct). Let me know if you have trouble with step...